# Completely Blank/White Render (2.8)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am having difficulty rendering my scene in Blender 2.8.

When I render my scene I receive  a completely blank/white screen. This is occurring when I attempt to use both Cycles and Eevee.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may resolve this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Check for hidden objects in the outliner, and check that your main camera hasn't accidentally been changed to some other object.

Comment: There are no hidden objects in the outliner and my main camera has not been changed to some other object. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to include more pictures of your settings, or head to https://blend-exchange.com/ and upload your file so someone can take a look.  If you [edit] your post it will be automatically bumped into the review queue to be reopened.